# ¿Atributos que re-aparecen?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema hace tiempo que no programaba en javascript y me sucede que me reaparecen los atributos

```
hidden=function(elemento){
console.dir(elemento.classList.contains("is-hidden"));
if(elemento.classList.contains("is-hidden")&& elemento.classList.contains("is-displayNone")){
    elemento.classList.remove('is-displayNone');
    setTimeout(function(){ elemento.classList.remove('is-hidden'); }, 200);
}else{
    elemento.classList.add('is-hidden');
    elemento.addEventListener("transitionend",()=>{
        elemento.classList.add('is-displayNone');
    });
}
```

};
me explico al dar click en un boton llamo a la funcion hidden con los atributos del  elemento que quiero ocultar pero por una extraña razon al quitar las clases is-hiden is-displayNone vuelven a aparecer las clases sin que les de click me puse a revisar y el evento solo se ejecuta una vez por click

```
<div class="panel">
<p class="button--cta panel__btn" id="a-btnAgregarP"><span class="icon-anadir"></span>agregar</p>
<p class="button--cta panel__btn" id="a-btnCambiarP"><span class="icon-editar"></span>cambiar</p>
<p class="button--cta panel__btn" id="a-btnEliminarP"><span class="icon-remover"></span>eliminar</p>
</div>
<section class="is-hidden is-displayNone" id="div-formAgregar">
    <h3 class="">Agregar Productos</h3>
    <form class="formulario--grid" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <span></span><label for="input-titulo_txt">Producto
        <input type="text" id="input-titulo_txt" name="input-titulo_txt">
      </label>
      <label class="label--textarea" for="textarea-contenido_txt">Descripcion
        <textarea id="textarea-contenido_txt" name="textarea-contenido_txt"></textarea>
      </label>
      <label for="input-categoria_num">Categorias
      <select id="input-categoria_num" name="input-categoria_num"><option value="1">Salado</option><option value="2">Dulce</option><option value="3">Bebidas</option><option value="4">otros</option></select>

      </label>
      <div class="fieldset">
        <button class=" subirImg" type="button">Cargar una imagen nueva</button>
        <button class=" escogerImg btn-ElegirImg1000" type="button">Elegir una imagen subida</button>
      </div>
        <label for="input-imagen_file" class="">Imagen Nueva
          <input type="file" id="input-imagen_file" class="input-imagen_file" name="input-imagen_file">
        </label>
        <label for="input-imagen_txt" class="hidden">Nombre de la imagen
          <input type="text" id="input-imagen_txt" class="input-imagen_txt" name="input-imagen_txt" disable="">
        </label> 

      <button class="button--cta" type="submit" name="input-agregar">Agregar</button>
    </form>
  </section>
```

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías agregar el código html asociado al problema?

Comment: Ya agrege el html Gracias por intentar ayudarme

Comment: El código que tienes se ve algo extraño, pero creo que entiendo que es lo que buscas; imagino que los primeros `<p>` son botones que realizan acciones de aparecer y ocultar divs, creo que puedes hacerlo de otra forma.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta creo que voy a cambiar por completo el codigo no habia pensado que en cada interacion se iba a añadir un escucha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya lo solucione dejo aqui el codigo con la solucion y explico lo que creo que pasaba

```
hidden=function(elemento){
console.dir(elemento.classList.contains("is-hidden"));
if(elemento.classList.contains("is-hidden")&& elemento.classList.contains("is-displayNone")){
    elemento.classList.remove('is-displayNone');
    setTimeout(function(){ elemento.classList.remove('is-hidden'); }, 200);
}else{
    elemento.classList.add('is-hidden');
    elemento.addEventListener("transitionend",(event)=>{
        if (event.target.classList.contains("is-hidden")) {
            elemento.classList.add('is-displayNone');
        };
    });
}
```

};

lo que pasaba era que el codigo agregaba el evento transition end por lo que al remover las clases is-displayNone y is-hidden se disparaba otra transición

> creo que voy a cambiar por completo el codigo no habia pensado que en
>   cada interacion se iba a añadir un escucha